# Problema redirecionamento CheckoutURL no Checkout CIelo

Tags: php, json, codeigniter, libcurl, e-commerce

Estou desenvolvendo o site do meu selo fonográfico com o framework CodeIgniter.
Nele eu venderei cd's físicos e digitais com a classe Cart.
Me inscrevi na Cielo essa semana e estou lendo assiduamente o Manual do Desenvolvedor.

No manual não contém informações para algumas dúvidas que não consegui solução.
A parte do carrinho já está funcionando OK, é no envio das informações que vão para a Cielo também estão OK.

Eu dei um echo no retorno, e a mesma aparece o pedido, ao meu ver tudo OK.

```
{"orderNumber":"2d0de5e0d0f2be876a8661233d66e93c","softDescriptor":"1070533359","cart":{"discount":{"type":"Percent","value":10,"isRequired":false},"items":[{"name":"Album - Faixa: Intro","description":"aaaa","unitPrice":1000,"quantity":1,"type":"Digital","sku":"c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b","weight":0}]},"shipping":{"type":"WithoutShipping"},"payment":{"boletoDiscount":0,"debitDiscount":10},"customer":{"identity":"14587524710","fullName":"Cliente","email":"cliente@email.com"},"options":{"antifraudEnabled":false},"settings":{"checkoutUrl":"https://cieloecommerce.cielo.com.br/TransactionalVNext/Checkout/Index/a2f81289-a0ec-4a1e-a5b2-9aeaceaeb394","profile":"CheckoutCielo","version":"2"}}
```

Solicitei a King Host ainda pouco para adicionarem o Certificado EV para mim, e liberarem o Mod Security específico para o Checkout Cielo.
Porém a página não é redirecionada para a CheckoutUL.
Será por falta desses componentes? Ou é algum erro meu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui resolver rapaziada.
Eu precisava redirecionar, não é automático.
Pra quem precisar:

```
$json = json_decode($response);
$checkoutUrl = $json->settings->checkoutUrl;
```

redirect($checkoutUrl); // redirect do codeigniter